# Does it make sense to have a longer `initialDelaySeconds` in case of readiness probes?

Tags: kubernetes

Based on [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#configure-probes) `initialDelaySeconds` gives some delay before the first readiness probe is checking the pod. But the only effect of readiness probe failure is that the pod is marked unready: Does not get traffic from services and also affects the deployment state.

So giving readiness checks some delay is not really effective for the majority of the applications: We want to make the pod early as soon as we can, meaning we need to check if it's ready as soon as possible.

Comment: Does your app have some initialization or warm up procedures?  If not, you may be able to avoid using the readiness check and rely only on liveness, this will give you the quickest time to handling traffic.

Comment: Yes, usually liveness and readiness are not using the same endpoints. Some of the application frameworks, like Quarkus, even tend to tread it separately.  My question focuses only on the readiness probe and especially on this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Things to consider:

1. No reason to set it earlier than the earliest possible startup time.
2. If you set it late, you are wasting resources (pods not receiving traffic): 1 minute delay for 60 pods is 1 hour.
3. How much resource does the readiness Probe consume? Does it make external calls (Database, REST, etc - IMHO this should be avoided)?
4. Can the pod serve the traffic? Are all the necessary connections (DB, REST) established, caches populated? - No reason to accept traffic if the pod cannot connect to the database/backend service.

To summarize:

- You want to minimize startup time
- You want to minimize readiness calls

Measure it, set it to the earliest possible time a pod can start.
If your pods are failing the readiness regularly causing restarts, increase it.

Comment: Default is 0 so if you leave it as is, what's the possible negative impact? If pod startup takes like 60 seconds and the probe period is 10 seconds the total expense is 6 HTTP calls to the readiness endpoint per pod. If you have like 1000 pods, then it can be 6000 HTTP calls but still, it's going to diminish compared to all that traffic readiness probe generates during the rest of the pod lifecycle.

Comment: Depends on the readiness probe implementation. (that 6000 HTTP calls could be 6000 user request). 
If the performance issue is negligible then of course you can set it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

> So giving readiness checks some delay is not really effective for the majority of the applications: We want to make the pod early as soon as we can, meaning we need to check if it's ready as soon as possible.

It depends what application you use. As you can read what [readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) is:

> Sometimes, applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic. For example, an application might need to load large data or configuration files during startup, or depend on external services after startup. In such cases, you don't want to kill the application, but you don't want to send it requests either. Kubernetes provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services.

If your application requires loading of large data files or configuration files at startup and it always takes e.g. 30 seconds, it makes no sense to start checking immediately after starting if the application is ready to run, because it will not be ready.
Therefore the `initialDelaySeconds` option is suitable for this and we can set the checking to start e.g. from 20 seconds instead of immediately

> `initialDelaySeconds`: Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness or readiness probes are initiated. Defaults to 0 seconds. Minimum value is 0.

Comment: If application startup takes 30 seconds, but you don't set the readiness probe initial delay, all that costs you is just a few HTTP requests to the readiness endpoint. By the definition you've cited the sole purpose of readiness probe existence is that it is capable of detecting when those initial startup thingies are taking a long time. So if we're OK with the cost of those few HTTP requests, can we spare the fine-tuning of the initial delay for readiness probes?

Comment: One of the scenarios I could imagine is when a database connection is checked actively during readiness probing. If the application is designed poorly, and the connection timeout is extremely long (like 60 seconds) then each readiness probe request can block for 60 seconds causing some unwanted consequences inside the application. BUT these issues would cause unwanted consequences any time when the database connection becomes temporarily unavailable. So in this case, failure of the initial readiness probing is just failing fast?

Comment: It depends on how big your cluster is. This option is best suited for a large cluster as unnecessary requests can degrade performance. If these few more requests don't matter to you, you don't need to set this option.